# Why can't I do .ajax ( return data; )? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get my function to return the data it got into another function but it doesn't seem to work? How can I get it to return the data?

```
function playerid(playername) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fn.php?playerid",
        data: "playername="+playername,
        success: function(data) {
            //$("#test").text(data);
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

I want to use it in another function like this

```
showBids(playerid(ui.item.value));




function showBids(playerid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "poll.php?",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 50000,
        data: "playerid="+playerid,
        success: function(data) {

            //.each(data, function(k ,v) {

            //})
            //$("#current_high").append(data);

            setTimeout("getData()", 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Isnt the data being returned from the nested function??

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your `playerid()` does not return anything, so what do you want to use? It has only `$.ajax()` call in it, no return statement (one of the callbacks in `$.ajax()` has return statement, but see below).

Secondly, JavaScript does some things asynchonously, otherwise every interface element would need to wait to react to user action until the AJAX call returns from the server.

Use event-based approach, by passing callbacks to some functions. Then, after they finish, just call the callbacks passing them the result:

```
function getplayerid(playername, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fn.php?playerid",
        data: "playername="+playername,
        success: function(data) {
            //$("#test").text(data);
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

and then use it like that:

```
getplayerid(ui.item.value, showBids);
```

(notice function name change since it does not actually *return* player ID, it *gets it* and passes it to callback)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use syncronous Ajax:

```
function playerid(playername) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fn.php?playerid",
        data: "playername="+playername,
        async : false   //making Ajax syncronous
    }).responseText;
}
```

Otherwise you need to use `showBids` function as callback:

```
function playerid(playername, callback) { 
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fn.php?playerid",
        data: "playername="+playername,
        success: function(data) {
           callback(data);
        }
     });
} 
//Usage
playerid(ui.item.value,showBids);
```

Comment: async false is deprecated, should I still use it? any other way?

Comment: @user1053408 If you don't want to use it, then only way is to use callback, what I was suggesting in my answer.

Comment: @user1053408 Could you show the link, where mentioned that syncronous ajax is deprecated.

Comment: @user1053408 I hope you would show a link from `Ecmascript standard`.If it is mentioned as deprecated in `jquery` since `1.8` version(which does not exist yet), it does not mean it is deprecated in Javascript :)